# pandas equivalent of percentage growth

Tags: pandas

Is there any way how to calculate the percentage growth (into the future) in pandas?

pandas have `.pct_change` method to calculate the percent change of some columns.

I would like to perform this in the future - my function does the work. however, I find it kind of weird to be using a for-loop for some calculations

```py
def cf_future_projection(
    cashflow_of_last_year: float,
    cashflow_pct_grow: float,
    last_observed_year: int,
    n_year_future: int = 5,
) -> dict:

    grow_values = {}
    grow_values[last_observed_year + 1] = cashflow_of_last_year * (
        1 + cashflow_pct_grow
    )
    for year in range(1, n_year_future):
        grow_values[last_observed_year + 1 + year] = grow_values[
            last_observed_year + 1 + year - 1
        ] * (1 + cashflow_pct_grow)

    return grow_values


cf_future_projection(150, 0.15, 2020, 15)
```

Any way how to do that in pandas and without a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `cf_future_projection(150, 0.15, 2020, 15)`, the basic calculation you are performing is `150*(1+0.15)^n for n years into the future`, so I think that your function, while nicely written, is unnecessarily complicated.

I don't know exactly what your use case is, but I think if you want to create a dataframe with new rows at the end, adding news rows one at a time is an expensive operation, and you probably don't want to use a for loop with dataframes as you mentioned. You might be better off taking the last row of an existing dataframe, creating a new dataframe with projected future values, and concatenating the original and new dataframes together.

For example, let's say you're starting with a dataframe that looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2019,2020],'value':[140,150]})
```

To do something similar to `cf_future_projection(150, 0.15, 2020, 15)`, we can take the starting value from the row of the dataframe corresponding to 2020, and then use a list comprehension to create our new future values and future years. If you like, you can wrap this operation in a function

```
year,value = df[df['year'] == 2020].values[0]
n = 5

year_future = [2020 + i for i in range(1,n+1)]
value_future = [value*(1+0.15)**i for i in range(1,n+1)]
df_future = pd.DataFrame({'year':year_future,'value':value_future})
df_future = pd.concat([df,df_future])
```

Result:

```
>>> df_future
   year       value
0  2019  140.000000
1  2020  150.000000
0  2021  172.500000
1  2022  198.375000
2  2023  228.131250
3  2024  262.350937
4  2025  301.703578
```